# Where can I find Putnam competition questions and solutions online?

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, contest-math, education

Math people:

Until recently, at least, there existed at least one Web page containing complete Putnam competition problems and solutions from the past twenty years or so.  In retrospect, I see that I should have downloaded everything there when I had the chance.  I spent about 20 minutes Googling today and couldn't find any such page.  Does anyone know if anything like this exists as of September 11, 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two sites that may help you:

- [Putnam exams](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/problems-math/)
- [Problem Solving and The Putnam Competition](http://www.math.hmc.edu/putnam/)

Comment: Thanks.  Your first link is more like what I'm looking for.  I'll wait a week or so and accept my favorite answer.

Comment: BTW, I found online an entire, excellent book of Putnam problems, solutions, and commentary.  It is probably illegal.  If someone is trying to control the online distribution of Putnam problems and solutions, they may be fighting a losing battle.